# .NET MVC - Default .onError handler for javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, default-value, onerror

is it possible to set a default .OnError handler for AjaxOptions in ActionLinks etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use an edited version of the default MVC javascript file.